# python 3.6 take user input from either pipe or cmd

Tags: input, cmd, pipe, python-3.6

Is there any way to accept either methods of input?
I'm currently taking input from cmd only by using `sys.argv[1]` but I need to make it to
accept both ways.
for example, the program should be able to take the input from either one of the following unix commands:

```
% cat text.txt | ./python3.py > out.txt

% ./python3.py text.txt > out.txt
```